# How to execute multiple programs in the same time with a .bat file

Tags: windows

I made 2 bat files to start apps with examples below:
My expectation is to execute them simultaneously, meaning after double click bat file, then 3 programs will pop up.

With the 1st example, the behavior is to execute outlook first, then both Mircrosoft Edge and OneNote still not pop up, until I stop Outlook.

Example 1

```
@echo off
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Outlook.lnk"
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Edge.lnk"
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OneNote.lnk"
exit
```

With the 2nd example, both Mrcrosoft Edge and OneNote were executed simultaneously, however Outlook not until I stop OneNote.

Example 2

```
 @echo off
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Edge.lnk"
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OneNote.lnk"
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Outlook.lnk"
exit
```

My questions is why it behaves like this way and how to make these 3 programs start up in the same time ?

Shown below is the Windows config:
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎10/‎27/‎2021
OS build    19044.1826
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0

Answer (score 0):

Normally to run tasks parallel, you should add `start /b` before the command to run.
The `start` command allows the command to be executed in another process, while `/b` prevents the opening of a new window.
In this specific case `start /b` does not work, for reasons unknown to me, but you can always use `cmd /c`.

Comment: This is not work for me, the behavior is the same with my examples.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: By adding cmd /c, from result point of view it behaves the same with start /b and my examples. I need to close OneNote to initialize Outlook. I don't why but I found that there is application dependency. For example, if I do: Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Teams, Excel file, Pdf files, with this apps combination, it works as expectation, all program could be start up in parallel. But if I add either Outlook or OneNote into the bat file, then I have to close the last app in order to trigger next app such as OneNote or Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

1)Run the first program using the start command.

2)Check the task list in a loop to see if the program has appeared there.

3)Impose some time limitation to the said loop.

4)Run the next program in case of success, exit with notification otherwise.

```
@ECHO 
OFF START program1.exe
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (
(TASKLIST | FIND /I "program.exe") && GOTO :startnext
:: you might add here some delaying
)
ECHO Timeout waiting for program1.exe to start
GOTO :EOF
:startnext
program2.exe
:: or START
program2.exe
```

Remember that the timing is not precise, especially if you are going to insert delays between the task list checks.

Comment: I replaced program1.exe and program2.exe with Mircrosoft Edge.exe and Outlook.exe then execute but nothing happen